# Why is testing compose navigation with the navigation drawer failing or terminates before destination route is reached?

Tags: android, unit-testing, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am testing the navHost in compose, I have 2 destinations and I use a navigation drawer to navigate to the destination. Checkout the sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/nic3point0/NavHost-Test).

I have create a test [file](https://github.com/nic3point0/NavHost-Test/blob/main/app/src/androidTest/java/dev/nic3point0/nevhosttest/NavigationTest.kt) that test if the destination was reached with `navHost_navigateToAbout_verifyDestinationIsReached()` test case but it fails.

I am also wondering if this is even possible or maybe I am doing it wrong

When I debug I noticed the test completes before the navigation drawer button is clicked, I think because it runs inside a coroutine. I have also tried to test using the [coroutine test dependency](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test). I am expecting the test to pass.